# JSON string is unexpectedly deserialized into object as a list

Tags: c#, json, servicestack, deserialization, json-deserialization

This JSON:

```js
{
    "Values": {
        "Category": "2",
        "Name": "Test",
        "Description": "Testing",
        "Expression": "[Total Items] * 100"
    }
}
```

Is being deserialized to this DTO using `JsConfig.ConvertObjectTypesIntoStringDictionary = true;`:

```cs
public class MyDto {
    public Dictionary<string, object> Values { get; set; }
}
```

Unexpectedly, the Expression property is deserialized as `List<object>` instead of `string` (see screenshot).

[image: Screenshot]

It seems the parser sees the opening bracket and tries to interpret the value as an array. Is there some way to turn this "type detection" off, or otherwise resolve the problem (without changing the DTO)?

I'm using ServiceStack v3.9.71.

Comment: Have you tried escaping the braket i.e. "\\[Total

Comment: It's even simpler than that: so long as the first character is something other than `[` it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Json.NET is able to deserialize your example JSON into an instance of your DTO class. It seems that the JSON parsing library you're using is buggy. Are you able to switch?

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        const string json = @"{
""Values"": {
    ""Category"": ""2"",
    ""Name"": ""Test"",
    ""Description"": ""Testing"",
    ""Expression"": ""[Total Items] * 100""
    }
}";
        var myDto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyDto>(json);
    }
}
public class MyDto
{
    public Dictionary<string, object> Values
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

[image: Json.NET works]

EDIT:

I switched my code to use ServiceStack.Text from NuGet and I was able to get the serialization to work perfectly:

`var myDto = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<MyDto>(json);`

Comment: I'm not able to switch unless ServiceStack's JSON serializer is pluggable (which I'm not sure about).

Comment: I tried it again without `JsConfig.ConvertObjectTypesIntoStringDictionary = true;` and it worked. I've been using that setting in my project for a long time and can't remember the motivation for adding it. I'll try removing it for a while and see what happens. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Interesting. That would do it. :)